# mysql subquery error while working with grant

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL gives me an error when I run this query:

```
mysqli_query($connect,"GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON myblog.*
    TO '$username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 
    (SELECT user_password from users where user_name = '$username')") 
or die("fail to grant ".mysqli_error($connect));
```

Whats wrong in this query? Is there any better solution?

Comment: If we don't know the error, how are we supposed to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support subqueries where the outer statement is a `GRANT`.

```
A subquery's outer statement can be any one of: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or DO.
```

Edit: Taken from the [MySQL docs on subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html).

Comment: In other words, to do what you're trying to do, you'll need to split it up into two separate queries, one to get the user password and one to run the GRANT.

Comment: im sorry for my incomplete question

Comment: i solved in other way just curious to know is it possible thanks